# How can I replace a variable and do conditional inside to work to interpolate as input of pacman [fix script]?

Tags: bash, heredoc, pacman-package-manager

First sorry, this is not the best title and it is difficult for me to understand, please consider edit.

I would like to understand what is happening

Steps:

1. First, run `docker pull oblique/archlinux-yay`.
2. Second, run `docker run -it --rm 52a1e19f71c7 bash` (`52a1e19f71c7` is the container id).
3. Do the following, download a tarball, create two variables and set with these strings, use EOS and do a if else condition and I expect to install with pacman a package.

```sh
[root@71cac056c2f9 ~]# curl -O https://gitlab.com/carlosal1015/dune-archiso-repository-extra/-/jobs/1079556435/artifacts/raw/x86_64/gconf-3.2.6+11+g07808097-10-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst
[root@71cac056c2f9 ~]# ISDEPENDS='true'
[root@71cac056c2f9 ~]# DEPENDENCIES_PACKAGE='gconf*'
[root@71cac056c2f9 ~]# sudo -H -i -u aur bash -e -x << EOS
if [ $ISDEPENDS ]; then sudo pacman -U `echo $DEPENDENCIES_PACKAGE | tr -d \'` ; fi
EOS
```

Type enter after last EOS.

```sh
[root@71cac056c2f9 ~]# error: 'gconf-3.2.6+11+g07808097-10-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst': could not find or read package
[root@71cac056c2f9 ~]# ls
gconf-3.2.6+11+g07808097-10-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst
```

And I would like to pass `sudo pacman -U gconf*` and start installation, because when I do the following works well.

```sh
[root@71cac056c2f9 ~]# pacman -U gconf*
loading packages...
resolving dependencies...
looking for conflicting packages...

Packages (6) dbus-glib-0.110-2  js78-78.8.0-1  libnsl-1.3.0-1  polkit-0.118-1  python-3.9.2-1
             gconf-3.2.6+11+g07808097-10

Total Download Size:    42.96 MiB
Total Installed Size:  153.36 MiB

:: Proceed with installation? [Y/n]
```

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried writing the command into a script file and just executing the script as sudo? You can create the script file by using `cat >> EOF << script.sh  multiline content EOF`

Comment: You can try `DEPENDENCIES_PACKAGE=$HOME/gconf*`

Comment: Thank you so much both, I was missed to explicit put the full path. Working in progress, I will try to do work with more of two packages and later put in a script.